# Convert a body vector relative to an aircraft, to a vector in ECEF space

Tags: coordinate-system, rotate, ecef

I am trying to solve for a problem where an observer is on an aircraft with a given pitch, roll, and yaw.  The observer is looking at an object which produces a line of sight vector that is measured in direction cosines (cos_x, cos_y, cos_z) relative to the body of the aircraft.  I would like to translate this vector into ECEF space so I can trace its intersection to a grid below it that is measured in ECEF coordinates.

I have started by developing a direction cosine matrix that translates the body of the aircraft to a geo frame by rotating in the order `ZYX`.  I then multiply the resulting direction cosine matrix by the vector of direction cosines.  I have encoded my method into Python, with the code shown below, but I am clearly missing something.  In this use case the body vector, measures as a vector of direction cosines is `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`, which implies the observer is looking straight out the nose of the aircraft.  The pitch is -10 degrees with 0 degrees in roll and yaw.  If the aircraft is pitched down, then the observer looking straight out the nose of the aircraft should be looking in the z direction as measured in ECEF.  Instead with the following code I get an ECEF vector of `[0.98480775, 0, 0.17364818]` which clearly does not intersect with the Earth.

```
from math import sin, cos, radians
import numpy as np


def aircraft_rotation(yaw: float, pitch: float, roll: float,
                      deg: bool = False) -> np.ndarray:
    if deg:
        yaw = radians(yaw)
        pitch = radians(pitch)
        roll = radians(roll)

    body_local = np.array([[cos(yaw)*cos(pitch),
                            cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)*sin(roll)-sin(yaw)*cos(roll),
                            cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)*cos(roll)+sin(yaw)*sin(roll)],
                           [sin(yaw)*cos(pitch),
                            sin(yaw)*sin(pitch)*sin(roll)+cos(yaw)*cos(roll),
                            sin(yaw)*sin(pitch)*cos(roll)-cos(yaw)*sin(roll)],
                           [-sin(pitch), cos(pitch)*sin(roll),
                            cos(pitch)*cos(roll)]])
    return body_local
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def body_to_ecef_vector(yaw: float, pitch: float, roll: float,
                        dir_cosine: np.ndarray, deg=False) -> np.ndarray:
    body_matrix = aircraft_rotation(yaw, pitch, roll, deg=deg)
    ecef_vector = np.matmul(body_matrix, dir_cosine)
    return ecef_vector
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pitch = -10.0  # degrees
    roll = 0.0  # degrees
    yaw = 0.0  # degrees
    cos_vec = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    vec = body_to_ecef_vector(yaw, pitch, roll, cos_vec, deg=True)
    print(vec)
```

Comment: You need 'lever arm offset', that is the location of your viewer (head) from the GPS antenna, this one https://chesapeaketech.com/wp-content/uploads/docs/SonarWiz7_UG/HTML/lever_arm_a_k_a__sheave_offsets_print.htm has a nice picture. You will also need the height of the ground to locate an intersection, this would have to be a DEM as the ground tends not to be very flat or you could use the time a beam of light takes to return from your laser scanner (divided by two: out and back) to work out how long your vector is to the intersection.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for.  I already have a body vector from the CG that is captured in the form of an array of direction cosines (i.e. cos_x, cos_y, cos_z).  I need to know how to transform the body vector to an ECEF vector. If yaw and roll is zero, the z component of the ECEF vector should be negative, and it is not in my implementation.

Comment: Jon, if I read this right you're asking about pure mathematics, there doesn't seem to be a GIS component. I suggest you post your question on StackOverflow stackoverflow.com or https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, it absolutely is a GIS question.  GIS involves mathematical transformations between various coordinate frames to reference the position and orientation of an object on the surface of the Earth.  In fact this is the fundamental basis for all GIS.  Not to mention their are many other such questions like this on this page.